# Create a Custom SearchBox UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Hi everyone I'm trying to create a custom searchbox for my app and here's my problem i want to change the white back color to a custom color when the searchbox selected

Here's my code:

```
<SearchBox x:Name="mySearchBox" 
FocusOnKeyboardInput="True"
QuerySubmitted="mySearchBox_QuerySubmitted"
Height="35"/>
```

Here's a picture from photoshop i created for how i want it to be

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `AutoSuggestBox` instead of `SearchBox` that's kinda deprecated in UWP. You can find the info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.searchbox).

[image: Screenshot]

You'll have to create a custom style to achieve what you want. You should copy the default style from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx) and edit it.

Comment: Thanks for helping